# Can I improve this AngularJS / AJAX javascript snippet?

Tags: javascript, ajax, design-patterns, angularjs, coding-style

I have the following general code.

```
MyClass.prototype.doSomething = function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: turl,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (_this) { //closure
            return function (data) {
                _this._angular_scope.$apply(function () {

                    _this.property = // extract stuff from 'data'
                    _this.analyzeContent() // do more stuff with it
                })
            }
        }(this)
    })
}
```

Basically, It's just a normal AJAX call. There's a...

(1) closure for "this" so that the success function can have access to my object and its state

(2) Inside, I return a function that performs something on data, but...

(3) I want everything that success does to be captured by AngularJS, so this function that parses the data will, *further*, wrap it's actions in an $apply call.

This works, but I can't help but wonder if there's a better way to accomplish this. It's right at the point where I have to think about what I'm doing every time I look at it due to the number of nested functions.

Is this okay, or is there a better recommended style?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that this code block is inside of an angular service, controller, or directive.  If it is not then there is a much broader issue at hand.  Angularjs comes with an [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) service that should be used in place of $.ajax here.  $http provides all the same capabilities as $.ajax with the added bonus that it is testable and it integrates with the angularjs digest cycle so you don't need to worry about the $scope.$apply() stuff.  I would do something like the following instead:

```
MyClass.prototype.doSomething = function () {
  var self = this;
  $http.get( turl ).success( function (data) {
    self.property = data.stuff;
    self.analyzeContent();
  } );
}
```

The important thing to remember here is that javascript uses function scope, not block scope.  As long as an object exists in the same function it is considered "in scope."  Since the value of `this` varies depending on the context you can just stick it in a variable (self) and be confident that the value is what you expect it to be.